# Python Frameworks vs Firebase

Tags: python, django, pyramid, firebase, bottle

Since Firebase can do user login as well as hold a lot of other stuff about users and their interactions with my app.

What are some of the advantages and disadvantages of using Firebase solely as a web framework, instead of using django, pyramids, bottle, etc etc?

http routing, etc etc.... I have that sorta stuff handle by another process...

So, if I'm looking basically to hold some user stuff and allow for user logins and user to user private/personal communications.

It seems firebase is an almost total solution, no?

I know this isn't a technical question, but I'm just looking for opinions from a realtime crowd....stackoverflow seems the best fit.

Answer (score 4):

Some contras of using Firebase:

- Your data is in an external server (deal-breaker for sensitive data)
- It costs money
- You have an additional dependency that you don't fully control (if they go out of service/business you might be in trouble)

You know the pros. If you think these are not relevant to you then go for it.

Comment: thank you for your opinion. it seems my thinking is correct that it can be used in a similar way as a python web framework.

Comment: That's definitely not true in the general case; only for yours.